# unable to apply different CSS classes to 2 svg images( both are clones of each other)

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, scss-mixins

I have 2 svg images in my html in 2 different divs.
On performing some action I am trying to hide one and display another by adding different css classes dynamically from my .ts.

But looks that even though my CSS class(`display:block`) gets applied to the 2nd svg but since the 1st svg is `display:none` both the svgs are alway hidden.

I think the CSS of the 1st svg's occurrence prevails over any other change made.

Can some one suggest what can be done to resolve this?

Note: I have used Figma tool to get these svgs.

```html
<div class="divMapGraphic">
   <div *ngIf="!btnCreateGrphcShow" class="ellipseEmptyStep">
        
   <svg width="13" [ngClass]="pointAClicked" height="14" viewBox="0 0 13 14" fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="6.5" cy="7" r="5.5" transform="rotate(-90 6.5 7)"             fill="url(#paint0_linear_38_12408)"
        stroke="#005C98" stroke-width="2" />
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_38_12408" x1="6.5" y1="0.5" x2="6.5" y2="13.5"
             gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
             <stop offset="0.53125" stop-color="#005C98" />
             <stop offset="0.53135" stop-color="#C4C4C4" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
        </svg>
       
                            
  </div>
  <div>
  <p [ngClass]="mapStep1TxtCss"
  *ngIf="!(unit.cfg.lateral == 0 || unit.cfg.lateral == null) && linearConfigStatus">Some text</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divMapGraphic">
  <div *ngIf="!btnCreateGrphcShow" class="ellipseEmptyStep">
 
<svg width="13" [ngClass]="pointCClicked" height="14" viewBox="0 0 13 14" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/svg">
<circle cx="6.5" cy="7" r="5.5" transform="rotate(-90 6.5 7)" fill="url(#paint0_linear_38_12408)"
  stroke="#005C98" stroke-width="2" />
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_38_12409" x1="6.5" y1="0.5" x2="6.5" y2="13.5"
  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0.53125" stop-color="#005C98" />
  <stop offset="0.53135" stop-color="#C4C4C4" stop-opacity="0" />
  </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  </svg>
                                
  </div>
  <div>
  <p [ngClass]="mapStep2TxtCss"
  *ngIf="!(unit.cfg.lateral == 0 || unit.cfg.lateral == null) && linearConfigStatus">Some text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You've duplicate id values haven't you? That's not valid.

Comment: Could you please post the JS code?

Comment: @RobertLongson If you are talking about the id values of '<linearGradient>', I tried changing them but still did not work. Updated the html image is the question above.

Comment: @JonasCastanheira the typescript code has nothing but assinging cssclass names to the variable you are seeing in the html.

Comment: @RobertLongson I added an Image assuming its easy to the eye than to traverse through lots of html code. But as you suggested, now I've added the html code of the divs that has these 2 svgs. pls let me know if something is wrong with my code.

Comment: presumably the fill in the second circle should point to paint0_linear_38_12409

Comment: @RobertLongson Wow..!! That did work , I should have looked at it more keenly. Thanks